# « Une dizaine » et le pluriel

Tags: accord, pluriel, nombres, noms-collectifs

Doit-on dire :

> *Une dizaine de personnes sont entrées.*

ou :

> *Une dizaine de personnes est entrée.* (Comme on l'entend dans les médias...)

Pour moi une dizaine, c'est le pluriel, non ?

Quelle différence avec :

> *Dix personnes sont entrées.*

Answer (score 4):

> Les noms tels que foule, multitude, troupe, masse, bande, file, majorité, grand nombre de, centaine, dizaine, centaine… sont morphologiquement au singulier. Employés seuls, ils appellent un verbe au singulier.

Ne pas confondre avec les adverbes de quantité tels que "la plupart (de/des)" et "une infinité de", qui eux, s'accordent bel et bien au pluriel.

Il faut également prendre en compte le sens de la phrase. Par exemple, on accorde
:

> Une file de jeunes attendent l’ouverture de la salle. (ce sont les jeunes qui attendent, non la file)

http://www.conjugaison.com/grammaire/sujet.html

Voir la section "6-2-2- Accord du verbe avec un nom collectif".

Comment: Cette citation n'est pas applicable à la question posée. Le paragraphe suivant serait approprié: "*Lorsqu’ils sont suivis d’un complément au pluriel, ils peuvent, selon l’interprétation, appeler un verbe au pluriel.*", et il donne la conclusion inverse (les deux sont corrects).

Answer (score 3):

Les deux accords sont acceptés car bien que le sujet soit au singulier, il s'agit d'un mot collectif (*dizaine*) dont le complément (*de personnes*) est au pluriel.

Le J.O. du 09/02/1977 a confirmé cette règle:

[image]

Cette tolérance s'applique aussi quand le complément n'est pas présent mais implicite par le contexte, on peut donc dire aussi bien « *Une dizaine sont partis* » que « *Une dizaine est partie* ».

La différence avec « *Dix personnes sont entrées* » est claire. Dans le deuxième cas, le singulier est impossible puisque le sujet est au pluriel . <s>*Dix personnes est entrée*</s>.